# Getting web content - browser does not support frames

Tags: java, html, parsing, html-parsing

I have a snippet of code like this:

```
webUrl = new URL(url);
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webUrl.openStream()));
```

When I try to get html content of some page I get response that my browser doesn't support frames. So I do not get the real html of the page.
Is there a workaround? 
Maybe to tell to the program to register as some browser?

For me it is critical only to get the html, then I want to parse it.

EDIT: Can not get src of the frame from the html in browser. It is hidden in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set a user-agent string in your HTTP request, so that the server thinks you are supporting frames. I suggest something like HtmlClient or HttpClient for this.

Answer (score 3):

The "You don't support frames and we haven't put sensible alternative content here" message will be in the `<noframes>` element. You need to access the appropriate `<frame>` element, access its `src` attribute, resolve the URI in it, and then fetch data from there.

Comment: Well I can not fine src attribute in iframe tag. And it seems that the content I need is outside ov the frame. <iframe id="lsadvert-bid-4010" name="banx-leftMenu_1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:120px; height:240px"></iframe>.. As you can see there is nothing here. Content I need is below this code.

Comment: Presumably it is being set up by JavaScript then, so you'll need to reverse engineer the JS to find out what it is doing.